# How to bind ppp0 interface (PPTP VPN) as 'external' in proxy server?

Tags: vpn, proxy, bind, route, pptp

I'm trying to bind ppp0 interface (PPTP VPN) as 'external' interface in proxy server (Tinyproxy).  Unfortunately it does not work.

Using route add -net default gw 10.9.0.1 I can make all the traffic go via VPN but this is not what I want.

My routes after ppp0 is up:

```
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.9.0.1        *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0 216-18-212-218. 192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0  0 eth0
```

ifconfig:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::21d:60ff:fe25:7ad6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:1d:60:25:7a:d6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 47533  bytes 31947804 (30.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 44946  bytes 6618945 (6.3 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 16436
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 13167  bytes 1604741 (1.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 13167  bytes 1604741 (1.5 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ppp0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1496
        inet 10.9.34.125  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.9.0.1
        ppp  txqueuelen 3  (Point-to-Point Protocol)
        RX packets 1088  bytes 568896 (555.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1328  bytes 167081 (163.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Do I need to add some other, specific route? Other proxy server? What IP Tinyproxy 'external should be bound to (I've tried both gw and peer)?